issue with how monotonically_increasing_id works
i have following code, which i use to add unique id to my DF. DF can have complete duplicate rows (all columns same), so i cannot use SHA or any other algo.
I am using ADB, DBR 14.3, spark 3.5.0
def create_one_partition (df: DataFrame = None):
    if df:
        if df.rdd.getNumPartitions() > 1:
            df = df.coalesce(1)
    return df
    

def add_consecutive_unique_id_column(df: DataFrame, unique_id_col_name: str = "unique_id"):
    """
    Add a consecutive unique identifier column to a DataFrame.

    Args:
    - df: DataFrame to which the unique identifier column will be added
    - unique_id_col_name: Name of the column for the unique identifier (default: "unique_id")

    Returns:
    - DataFrame: DataFrame with a consecutive unique identifier column
    """
    # If the temporary unique_id_tmp column doesn't exist, create it
    if "unique_id_tmp" not in df.columns:
        df = create_one_partition(df)
        df = df.withColumn("unique_id_tmp", monotonically_increasing_id())

    # Use row_number to generate consecutive unique IDs based on the temporary unique_id_tmp column
    window_spec = Window.orderBy("unique_id_tmp")
    df = df.withColumn(unique_id_col_name, row_number().over(window_spec))

    # Drop the original unique_id_tmp column as it's no longer needed
    df = df.drop("unique_id_tmp")

    ##return df
    return df

but issue with this code is, when i try to use resultant DF in my code for any purpose. the value this column keeps changing. It is behaving as if spark is not generating values, but keeping this code as view, making this code completely useless.
any idea? to get around this? so DF doesnt keep generating this column value again and again.

When you call a transformation on a DataFrame, such as withColumn or drop, Spark creates a logical plan but does not execute it immediately. Instead, it waits for an action to be triggered, such as calling show or collect, to execute the plan and produce the result.
As you mentioned, consecutive unique IDs are generated using the monotonically_increasing_id function. However, since this function relies on the internal Spark task IDs, the generated IDs may not be consistent across different actions or executions of the DataFrame. This is why you observe different values for the unique identifier column each time you use the DataFrame.
You can cache the DataFrame after adding the unique identifier column to ensure consistent results.
I have tried the below approach:
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id, row_number
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

def add_consecutive_unique_id_column(df, unique_id_col_name="unique_id"):
    if "unique_id_tmp" not in df.columns:
        df = df.withColumn("unique_id_tmp", monotonically_increasing_id())
    window_spec = Window.orderBy("unique_id_tmp")
    df = df.withColumn(unique_id_col_name, row_number().over(window_spec))
    df = df.drop("unique_id_tmp")
    df = df.cache()
    return df

df_with_unique_id = add_consecutive_unique_id_column(df, "unique_id")
df_with_unique_id.show()

Results:
+---+----+---+---------+
| id|name|age|unique_id|
+---+----+---+---------+
|  1|John| 25|        1|
|  2|Jane| 30|        2|
|  3| Sam| 35|        3|
|  1|John| 25|        4|
|  4| Tom| 40|        5|
|  2|Jane| 30|        6|
|  5|Kate| 35|        7|
|  6|Jack| 40|        8|
+---+----+---+---------+


In the above code, I have created a sample DataFrame with columns "id", "name", and "age" containing duplicate rows. Then, I called the add_consecutive_unique_id_column function to add a consecutive unique identifier column called "unique_id" to the DataFrame. The resulting DataFrame, df_with_unique_id, will have the added column with unique IDs.

thank you for detailed reply. but i can see 2 issues if i implement cache. this code is part of a framework, and some of the data is running into billion rows. so cache will not be persistent too. if cache spill, Databricks will calculate the result. 2nd issue is, as this is a util/framework, i will not know if user will ever release the cache. it may create OOM after multiple runs.
